# Derivative of a continuous function

Tags: derivatives

Suppose we have a continuous function f:R→R. Suppose also that for a certain point c, lim(x→c)f′(x) exists. Must f′(c) exist as well, and be equal to this limit?

This isn't quite the same as asking if derivatives are always continuous. The well-known function f(x)=x^2*sin(1/x) is continuous and differentiable everywhere, but its derivative has no limit at x=0. I'm wondering if the derivative of a continuous function can have a discontinuity where its limit does exist.

**I know this is a duplicate.. but the original question has a wrong answer. 
It assumed that f is differentiable (except at x=a) at an open interval which containing a .**

Comment: If $\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)$ exists, then by definition we **must** have that $f$ is differentiable on a deleted neighbourhood of $c$. Otherwise the expression doesn't even make sense and the limit isn't defined.

Comment: @Jason so you are saying that the assumptions are necessary?